# Shiny App ui.R includeHTML displays HTML but htmlOutput server.R is not displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to display  code from the server.R code so that I can drive the Amazon ads based on user selection in the UI.  The HTML displays fine in the ui.R with indluceHTML, but does not when I move the html code do the server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc") # this code here does NOT produce the HTML output
),

includeHTML("include.html") # this code produces the HTML output
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("include.html"))
}
output$inc<-renderUI({getPage()})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is the html that I need to render - some fields xxx have had values redacted.  The code in the include.html comes from Amazon so that I can connect to their add page.  Ultimately I need to dynamically change the default_search_phrase based on user input.

include.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";
amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "bottom";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_title = "...on Amazon";
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Star Wars Black Series 6 Inch";
amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "xxxxxxxxxx";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

if I put something simple in the include.html file, both methods work:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

The final rendered HTML looks something like the following circled in green:
[image: HTML Result]

Comment: do you want to actually show/render the html to the user, or do you just want to just have the javascript be updated?

Comment: I want to render the Amazon ad to the user which is the HTML "result".  I added a photo to the description for clarity.

Comment: and the only thing that you want to make dynamic about the add is the suggested search phrase?

Comment: Correct. The customer selects the series which filters the figures and the condition. Each time the customer changes the series or figure I want to query for what the user has selected in the series and figure fields. The series field is set in the server.r code

Comment: it sounds like you want to search for adds based on user feedback, correct? if you just want to update the "default search field" in the add search bar, then it's pretty simple. if you want to show adds based on user feedback, that's a bit more invovled

Comment: And `include.html` is in the `www` folder ? Not sure, but I would try `includeHTML("www/include.html")` in `server.R`.

Comment: Stephane L. - I have tried to place the .js in the same directory last he app.R and in the sub "www" directory.  Both locations give the same result.  The includeHTML works in the ui.R and not when in the server.R.  Chris - I am looking to show dynamically render the javaScript HTML output based on user selected choices for Series and Figure.